# Can't vertically align a link in a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

My wish is simple - to make a clickable cell (i.e. cell with a link) with a minimum height requirement (40 px in this case) ant vertically centered text. Here's what I come up with so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

table.test td {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;}

table.test td.cell a {
  background-color: #FFF5EE;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%; width:100%;
  min-height: 40px;}

table.test td.cell a:hover, td.cell a:active {
  background-color: #D2691E;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"><a href="www.google.lt">Google</a></td>
    <td>Line1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"><a href="www.google.lt">Google</a></td>
    <td>Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything's ok, but I can't get the text aligned (centered) vertically :/ The `vertical-align` property doesn't work in this case.

Here's the example in action ([link](http://soften.ktu.lt/~s665731/tryme.htm)).

Comment: Still no luck. Decided to make a special class (with predefined cell height) for those cases where there is more than one line in the second cell.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
height: 100%;
```

from

```
table.test td.cell a { ... }
```

and add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to

```
table.test td { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css to center and vertically align the text:

```
  table.test td { 
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle
  }
```

Comment: Well it does align horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: @Mike this is turning out to be more difficult that i assumed, Pheonix's answer is good when setting the line-height to 4em, but if the table cell grows in height its still donst fill the remaining height, i will mark this question as a favorite to see what the out come for you is, good luck with it

Comment: I also thought that it's a simple problem, until several hours of search / trial / error did not gave any results :)

Answer (score 0):

use vertical-align:

http://jsfiddle.net/pN4pQ/1/

Comment: Did that. But again - I need a _clickable cell_ (i.e. so that it would be possible to go to a link by pressing anywhere on the cell space) with vertically aligned text. In your example only text is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ::

```
.cell {
    line-height: 4em;
}
```

and for horizontal alignment

```
.cell {
    line-height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HA6Wq/1/

Comment: @Greg yes you are right... this does not seem to work then the lines in the right column increase, then we will need to increase the `line-height` also... so this is not an ideal solution. but i couldn't get this to work any other way :-/

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made a lot of modification and included jquery but i think it's what you want

So here we go :

```
<html>
<head>
//Really important, put this if you want the jquery to work
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style>

table.test td
{border:1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;}

.cell 
{background-color: #FFF5EE; 
cursor:pointer;}

.hover
{background-color: #D2691E;}


</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            //Replace your link and redirect when you click on the cell
        $(".cell").click(function() { window.location = 'http:\www.google.lt'});
            //Since you can't put a hover class on a td, you have to do it in jquery
        $(".cell").hover(function() { $(this).addClass("hover");}, function() {$(this).removeClass("hover");});

    });
</script>


</head>
<body>

<table class="test">
<tr>
<td class="cell">Google</td>
<td>Line1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cell">Google</td>
<td>Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3</td>
</tr>
</table>

</table>
</body>
```

And I've put the min-height as a height in the td style

I know it's a lot of change but it's working :)

And here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d9CGX/

EDIT :

I've updated the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d9CGX/2/ So you can have multiple link

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It does work, but it's very strange that rather simple problems must resort to using JS :/ I'm still hoping there's a CSS based solution, since in my case there are a dozen of cells with different links in them.

Comment: I hope you'll find it, but I thinks it's the easiest solution, that will be working in every browser ...

Comment: The multiple link problem is fixed in the new fiddle, so it would juste be the JS Problem, but i'm sure it will come handy in another situation

Answer (score 0):

just if it helps I did this and switched the  link to a javascript onclick:

```
.tdmenu 
{
    vertical-align : middle;
    padding-left : 10px;
    padding-right : 10px;
}
.tdmenu:hover
{
    background-color : rgb(220,220,220); /*set color to whatever you like*/
    cursor : pointer;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="height : 40px; background-color : rgb(255,255,255);">
<tr style="height : 100%;">
    <td class="tdmenu" onclick="document.location='Default.aspx';">Home</td>
    <td class="tdmenu" onclick="document.location='Projects.aspx';">Projects</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Seems to play nice.

Answer (score 0):

I was involved with a similar situation and it took many hours to figure out. This method will allow you to vertically align and center. Replace your

```
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com"></a>
```

code with this.

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <a href="http://www.linkhere.com" style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;align-text:center;">
            Link contents go here
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Put the contents of the link inside the div table-cell of course. This will stretch the link also to the edges of the container your using for this code. Hope that helps.