# Correct CSS formatting

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have a PHP table which loops out all the rows. I want to have the text float in the middle of the table row yet have the whole width+height of the row as an anchor.

What I have is 9 TD in each row. So I applied an anchor to every TD. I tried to do td p and set the height to 50% or vertical-align middle but that doesn't work. I think I need to start all over again with the CSS.

My question is:

Does anyone have CSS code that will apply the TR height to 70px, width 100%. TD to be 70px high. Then the whole area of the TD (or TR) to be an anchor clickable with text floating in the middle of the TR height.

Regards
Gambit

Update:

Here is my CSS and PHP http://jsfiddle.net/j8ptc/ obviously it wont display correctly because its PHP

Comment: Can you share any code / what have you tried?

Comment: @TheGambit Try posting what you have on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This will make it easy for us to see your issue and play around to fix it.

Comment: @TheGambit, how much text is supposed to be in each cell? Will it occupy only one line or several lines?

Comment: @caligula Probably max is 3 lines

Comment: Could you update your fiddle with the generated HTML and not the PHP?

Comment: @TheGambit, do you really need to use `table`? In my opinion it is impossible to achieve the required result with table. You never can reliably set `td`, `tr`'s dimensions, cause if a content will be larger than expected, browser will redraw table.

Comment: @caligula It looks like tabular data to me.  The real question is, should it still use the table/table-row/table-cell family of display attribues? Or should it even be changed/controlled at all?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it.

```
 table {
   width: 100%
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
table td a{
   height: 70px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 3px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

table td a {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
}​
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/wcafu/2/) with the result.

EDIT:

Removing

```
line-height: 70px;
```

and adding

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

will account for long lines of text, however it makes the vertical alignment difficult.

It would appear that this could pose a problem if the content of the cells is dynamic (or otherwise unknown).  [Here's another question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939148/cant-vertically-align-a-link-in-a-table-cell) for reference.  Good luck!

Comment: It does not comply to the condition. Table does not stretch to 100% width. Also there might be much more text then simple 1,2,3. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcafu/3/

Answer (score -1):

Use the onclick="" attribute inside the TR or TD element to have the whole row or just the whole cell clickable.

Use [this site](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) to help with the vertical alignment.

Comment: Never ever ever use the onclick="" attribute.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is likely to leave out your anchors entirely, and instead add a click event to the rows (or, better yet, to the table, and detect the target). Using CSS, you can then change the cursor to indicate a link.

PHP:

```
echo '<table id="yourTable">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr class="record" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">';
    echo '<td>'.$row['company'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['project'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['assignee'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['current_milestone'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$date=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['start_date'])).'</td>';

    // etc.

    echo '</tr>'
}

echo '</table>';
```

JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById('yourTable');

table.onclick = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;

    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        id;

    if (target.tagName === 'TD')
    {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if (target.tagName === 'TR' && target.className === 'record')
    {
        window.open('update.php?id=' + id, 'updateWindow');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
tr
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

td
{
    height: 70px;
}
```